# Search API highlight

Tags: views, search

using the search API module I highlighted the search text. Key words take the whole width of the block, how to insert them in the text? my current setup is:

Highlighting prefix : `<p class="views-highlight">`
Highlighting suffix : `</p>`

CSS:  `.views-highlight {color: black; background-color: yellow;}`

[my search results](http://www.s1biose.com/rechercher?keys=savon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be wrapping your keywords in **p** tags. **P** is a block-level element, and that is why it stretches 100% width of your container.

Use **mark**, **span** or any other inline-level element instead.

Comment: thank you it works. Do you know why the keyword title is not brought to light

Comment: in your Search Highlight settings, check "Exclude fields from excerpt" selection and make sure Title field is not checked. And you're welcome.

Comment: no it is not checked and it still does not work for the title. A second question also, I shows the results with a view. When there is no result Search displays all the content, how to tell him not display anything when there is no result?

Comment: this discussion is out of scope of your original question. Please post any other questions as separate questions.